# docker application not communicate with docker mysql container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I just encountered a problem. I am dockerizing a springboot application with MySQL as a database it is perfectly working in a local setup. But when I try to dockerize the application using `docker-compose`, MySQL container is working fine and is accessible in my workbench but my application is not able to access it throwing the communication link failure.

This is the compose file I am using:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart:unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=baskartest
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./bezkoder-app
    restart:on-failure
      env_file: ./.env
      ports:
        - 8084:8080
      environment:
        SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
            "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/baskartest?useSSL=false",
            "spring.datasource.username" : "root",
            "spring.datasource.password" : "root",
            "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
            "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
          }'
      volumes:
        - .m2:/root/.m2
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
```

MySQL is working fine but my app in services is not able to communicate with it.

Here is what I see:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any particular error you are seeing on the app side?

Comment: Port number used in spring.datasource.url is incorrect. You mentioned 3306 but it should be 3307 because HOST port mentioned in mysqldb service is 3307

Comment: @RohitAgarwal 3307 is tha local port and 3306 is the host port.In fact i try with 3307 also but it is not working but I connect to 3307 from my workbench.

Comment: Ok, If any error is coming can you please share that to debug further.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal I just add the error screen in the description

Answer (score 0):

I have done small changes in `docker-compose.yml` file, please use this one. It is working fine.

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: MYSQL_DB
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=baskartest
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
  app:
    build: ./bezkoder-app
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8084:8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://MYSQL_DB:3306/baskartest
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
```

Comment: the same error still coming.

Comment: Ohh ok can you please run  this command and see your app is available ? docker container ls

Comment: my app is not available because it is not complete the build part due to this error.But my sql container is available.

Comment: ok Can you please run this command once                                                      
docker-compose down --rmi all and after then run docker-compose up

Comment: It should work this time. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Answer (score 0):

In my short experience with Docker and containers communicating with eachother, I've found that `localhost` configuration URL's aren't working. Because one container can't communicatie with another container using just `localhost:[PORT]`.

A lazy way for me to fix this is to work out a static IP address of the machine the containers are running on. Then use this (local) IP address instead of localhost to define the endpoint of the database.

**In my situation** with Redis I'm doing it like this:

```
return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("192.168.1.201", 6379));
```

**In your situation**, you might want to use a Datasource URL like this:

```
- SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://[STATIC_IP_OF_MACHINE]:3306/baskartest
```

*i.e. `...192.168.1.100:3306/baskartest...*`

Comment: not working still the same error.