# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure - Fails only when deploying the app in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

Hello I am trying a spring boot mysql with docker.
I was able to test my application when my app is running on local and connecting the my-sql  which is launched as docker container.

But when try the same application deployed in docker (now both my app and db are deployed in docker) it fails with  Communications link failure

I think we may need to make some correction in the url.
Can you please help.

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=MySqlApp-Docker
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3366/docker-mysql
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  ## Mysql database
  local-mysql:
    container_name: local-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3366:3306
    expose:
      - 3366
    restart: unless-stopped    
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_inventory_service:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dockermysql
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - odr-network      
      
  app-mysql:
    container_name: app-mysql
    image: spring-docker-mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - local-mysql
    networks:
      - odr-network
      
networks:
  odr-network:   
    driver: bridge
```

**Error Log**

```
app-mysql    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at com.spring.docker.mysql.MySqlApp.main(MySqlApp.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  ... 54 common frames omitted
app-mysql    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  ... 57 common frames omitted
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | 2023-01-04 14:55:35.275  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    |  at com.spring.docker.mysql.MySqlApp.main(MySqlApp.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
app-mysql    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  ... 54 common frames omitted
app-mysql    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar:8.0.31]
app-mysql    |  ... 57 common frames omitted
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | 2023-01-04 14:55:35.281  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
app-mysql    | 2023-01-04 14:55:35.532  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
app-mysql    | 2023-01-04 14:55:36.534 ERROR 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
app-mysql    | 
app-mysql    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74450890/7871511

See if it helps

Comment: It did not work. Even I tried to add various parameter (useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10)like the following in the DB URL. Still getting the same issue. I am able to connect to the DB using DBeaver. Connection fails only through docker app during connection pool creation on the start up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MySQL` and `Spring Boot` application runs in the seperate container. So I recommend using the internal address and port instead of using external port and address.

To do this, change your `application.properties` file this way.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://local-mysql:3306/docker-mysql
```

Although it is the correct solution that ssj specifies, you can use the restart policy in your `app-mysql` image, similar to your `local-mysql` image instead.

```
restart: unless-stopped
```

This allows your `Spring Boot` application to restart due to errors until your database application is ready and available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the **depends_on** tag of docker compose.
The tag 'depends_on' regulates the order in which the containers are launched using compose, but it is not guaranteeing that the container that we depend on will be ready so that current container will start without any problem.

The possible solution is we need to make the current container wait until the container that we depend on is completely ready.

Many such wait tools are discussed in the following url.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

I used the **docker-compose-wait** from https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait.

With that, I modified by Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait 
RUN chmod +x /wait
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
CMD ["/wait", "java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And Made corrections to the compose as follows, ie I added a **command** tag and required **environment** variables for the tool

```
command: sh -c "/wait && java -jar app.jar"
environment:
  WAIT_HOSTS: local-mysql:3306
  WAIT_TIMEOUT: 300
  WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL: 30
  WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT: 30
```

And if you see that, when run from the container, I no more depend on the container's exported port. Because the **exported port** comes into picture only when you are trying to access the container from host machine where your docker engine is running. As my **app** and **dbserver** ie local-mysql (in this case), connected in the same network, I simply access my DB server with **container-name**:**port** [the port on which the server is running not on the exposed port]

My New DB URL :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://local-mysql:3306/dockermysql
```